# How can I blur only part of image using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a service from amazon that returns the cordinates of the face from the picture !!

```
{ "Top" : 0.16105769574642181, "Left" : 0.32451921701431274, "Height" : 0.2788461446762085, "Width" : 0.27764421701431274 }
```

and I want to blur only the face (or a square) from the image. I am trying ImageMagick, but am not able to make it work!! So, I found a different way to do it, but am unable to put it into code
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#read_mask

If you know any NPM that can help or how to do it with ImageMagick that would be very helpful

Answer (score 3):

So I found a solution that is pretty simple:

> image => url or path ; 
>   faceDetails => is the array of faces aws rekognition returned facesDetails.boundinBox is the object you see in the question

```
    let blur = function(image, faceDetails) {
        let img = gm(image);

        img.size(function(err, value){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {

                faceDetails.forEach((faceDetail) => {
                    const box    = faceDetail.BoundingBox,
                        width  = box.Width * value.width,
                        height = box.Height * value.height,
                        left   = box.Left * value.width,
                        top    = box.Top * value.height;

                    img.region(width, height, left, top).blur(0, 50);
                });

                img.write(__dirname + '/archive/resize.jpg', function (err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('done Wrting .....');

                    }else{
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```